# Visibility of changes within same transaction

Tags: jdbc, transactions, jdbctemplate

I am working with JDBC in `setAutoCommit(false)` mode.

Inside the same transaction I execute multiple Statements for insert, update and select.

**The question is**: should these changes be visible inside the same transaction for subsequent operations? What specific rules are there? Is it vendor-specific? Is it driver-specific? Or whatever?

I work with mysql-connector-java 8.0.11, JDBC 4.2, java 8 and in my case **no changes are visible**, e.g.

```
  try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlInsert, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
                statement.setString(1, "testData");
                statement.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("After insertion:");
                // jdbc findAll impl.
                findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
                conn.commit();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                conn.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
```

Here, the inserted uncommitted data is actually NOT visible inside same transaction!

However, if I do the same stuff with Spring's jdbcTemplate and Spring's DataSourceTransactionManager, like this:

```
final DefaultTransactionDefinition defaultTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();

defaultTransactionDefinition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
TransactionStatus transaction = txManager.getTransaction(defaultTransactionDefinition);

try {
    // jdbcTemplate insert impl.
    insert("testData");
    System.out.println("After insertion:");
    // jdbcTemplate findAll impl.
    findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    txManager.commit(transaction);
} catch (Exception e) {
    txManager.rollback(transaction);
}
```

The inserted uncommitted data is actually visible inside same transaction!

I found no explanation in JDBC specification, and am confused with it.

Please, explain this behavior.

P.S. I am aware of different isolation levels, but they basically apply to concurrent transactions, not to the same one.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You are currently hiding details. For example: what does that `findall()` method do? I would guess that it will create a new connection, and therefor have its own transaction.

Comment: True, that's was the point. I created a new connection in findAll() method. If I implement all the logic findAll() inside the given connection, all data is visible. Never thought, select query would affect the current transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the additional information in your comments that the `findAll` creates a new connection, the problem is that you are using one connection+transaction to update the data, and another connection+transaction to select the data.

A select query is affected by a transaction: the transaction determines what is visible or not. You have connection 1 with transaction 1 where you modified data (not yet committed), and connection 2 with transaction 2 that performs a select. Given transaction 1 is not yet committed, transaction 2 cannot see the data changed by transaction 1.

If you use `JdbcTemplate` and a Spring transaction manager, things change, because Spring does additional work to ensure that it uses the same connection and transaction for both the update and the select.